# What does this distribution mean?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm kind of embarrassed that I don't fully get this, but I assume it is because the example is using letters for a sample space instead of numbers.

```
Sample space = {a,b,c,d,e,f} with equal probability

outcome |  a  |  b  |  c  |  d  |  e  |  f  |
x       |  0  |  0  | 1.5 | 1.5 |  2  |  3  |
```

Is this saying that `P(X=0) = a + b`? Or `P(X=0) = 1/6 + 1/6`?

Could someone please explain this is simple terms (like a dice throw example, perhaps)?

Comment: You did not say what the question was. Presumably the random variable $X$ is defined to be $0$ at $a$ and $b$, $1.5$ at $c$, and so on. And we are asked a question about $X$, such as the mean of $X$. But without the question it is hard to discuss details.

Comment: I've asked a concept question, so there isn't really a question. But I guess finding `P(X=1.5)` would help me understand.

Comment: $1/6+1/6$.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: There are six equally likely outcomes. Think of them as the outcomes of a roll of a fair die instead of a, b, c, d, e, f if you wish.  Suppose you win an amount $X$ whose value depends on the outcome of the die roll. You win nothing if you roll a 1 or a 2, 1.5 if you roll a 3 or a 4, 2 if you roll a 5, and 3 if you roll a 6. So $X$  takes on values 0, 1.5, 2, and 3 with probabilities $\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{3}$, $\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{3}$, $\frac{1}{6}$ and $\frac{1}{6}$ respectively,

Comment: @DilipSarwate, this is exactly what I needed, thank you. If you're willing to post it as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @MaxMackie Done! with minor changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are six equally likely outcomes `a, b, c, d, e, f`. Think of them as the outcomes of a roll of a fair die whose faces are marked `a, b, c, d, e, f` instead of the usual $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$. Suppose you win an amount $X$ whose value 
depends on the outcome of the die roll. The table shows that you win $0$ 
if you roll an `a` or a `b`,  $1.5$ if you roll a `c` or a `d`, $2$ if you roll 
an `e`, and $3$ you roll an `f`. So X takes on values $0, 1.5, 2$, and $3$ with probabilities $\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{3}$, 
$\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{3}$, $\frac{1}{6}$ and $\frac{1}{6}$ respectively,